# How to check php function from file with interactive console?

Tags: php, debugging

I have a php file with includes and functions:

```
 <?php
        include_once ('conf.php');
        include_once ('library/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
        ...
        $dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $CONF_DB['host'] . ';dbname=' . $CONF_DB['db_name'], ....
        ...
        function function1 () {
        ..
        }

        function function2 (var1) {
        ..
        }
        ...
        ?>
```

I modified one of function and now want to check is it returning correct data or no (and according code structure it's not convenient to separate function code cause a lot of context-dependent variables inside)

Is it possible to test what return one patricular function with console?
like this:

```
php -a file_with_functions.php -some_key 'print_r function2(123)'
```

Can't figure out how to make it with [interactive console](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php) or debuggers like [psysh](http://psysh.org/) so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with PHPUnit https://phpunit.de/
Just write a simple test with an assertion of what you expect